# Calling Grpc gateway inside the for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, grpc

I am trying to call grpc API using node js and `"@grpc/grpc-js": "^1.3.0"` inside the for loop and want to store the result  `response` in DB. The number contains more than 10000 values. I want to fetch one by one. But if I use for loop it does not wait until all processes complete. Is there any way I can increment the number in for-loop after the execution of the grpc call and save data in the DB finish.

number = 100000

```
async function SaveNumber(number,client) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        console.log(i)
        client.GetNumberDetails({ "number": i }, async function (err, response) 
           {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                await dbSave.SaveNumberDetails(response)
            }

        })    
    }
 }
```

Comment: can `client.GetNumberDetails` return a promise - then you can await it.

Comment: i try to add await near to ```client.GetNumberDetails``` its giving me error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for your calls to `GetNumberDetails`. You can wrap the call into a Promise and wait for it.

```
async function SaveNumber(number,client) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       client.GetNumberDetails({ "number": i }, function (err, response) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err);
          } else {
            resolve(response);
          }
       });
    });
    await dbSave.SaveNumberDetails(response)
  }
}
```